# Embarassingly parallelizable computation with CUDA, how to start?

Tags: optimization, parallel-processing, cuda

I need to accelerate many computations I am now doing with PyLab. I thought of using CUDA. The overall unit of computation (A) consists in doing several (thousands) entirely independent smaller computations (B). Each of them involves, at their initial stage, doing 40-41 independent, even smaller, computations (C). So parallel programming should really help. With PyLab the overall (A) takes 20 minutes and (B) takes some tenth of a second.

As a beginner in this realm, my question is what level I should parallelize the computation at, whether at (C) or at (B).

I should clarify that the (C) stage consists in taking a bunch of data (thousands of floats) which is shared between all the (C) processes, and doing various tasks, among which one of the most time consuming is linear regression, which is, too, parallelizable! The output of each procedure (C) is a single float. Each computation (B) consists basically in doing many times procedure (C) and doing a linear regression on the data that comes out. Its output, again, is a single float.

I'm not familiar with CUDA programming so I am basically asking what would be the wisest strategy to start with.

Comment: You might want to consider leveraging multiple CPU cores, SIMD, etc, before you commit to CUDA.

Comment: @PaulR, if coding for SIMD means hand coding in assembly for one of the SIMD instruction sets, then I don't agree that you may want to consider SIMD before CUDA. In that case, coding for CUDA is much easier (since you write in C/C++) and results in faster code (with a possible exception if your system is unusually balanced, with a very fast CPU and a slow GPU). Technologies like Microsoft PPL or AMP can generate SIMD code but they have their own learning curves and it may not be any easier to get started with them (though I haven't checked).

Comment: @Roger Dahl: well there are pros and cons for both SIMD and GPGPU, and the "best" solution will depend on the nature of the application, e.g. for production code for wide distribution and a long life-cycle the arguments will be very different than for say, R&D code running on a single machine. Having said that, in my experience SIMD is applicable to a larger problem domain than GPGPU, has an easier learning curve, is more portable, and has fewer constraints than GPGPU. Note that the C/C++ argument does not really apply as SIMD can be coded using intrinsics.

Comment: @PaulR: I agree that in general, the best solution depends on the nature of the application. My comment was based on the OP wanting to accelerate what I assumed to be an in-house app (since it's running under PyLab). Intrinsics are still assembly, so I don't understand how that negates the C/C++ argument. I'd be interested in finding out more about your thoughts in this, so I set up channel in chat. Please drop in if you have time! http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16201/simd-vs-gpgpu

Comment: @Roger: sure - I'll post come comments on that chat thread...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An important consideration when deciding how (and if) to convert your project to CUDA is what type of memory access patterns your code requires. The GPU runs threads in groups of 32, called warps, and to get the best performance, the threads in a warp should access the memory in some basic patterns, that are described in the CUDA Programming Guide (included with CUDA). In general, the more random the access patterns, the more likely the kernel is to become memory bound. In that case, the compute power in the GPU cannot be fully utilized.

The other main case when the compute power in the GPU cannot be fully utilized is if there is conditional logic and loops that causes the threads in a warp to run through different code paths, as the GPU has to run all the threads in the warp through each code path.

If you find that these points may cause issues for your code, you should also do some research to see if there are known alternative ways to implement your code to run better on the GPU (this is often the case).

If you see your question about at which level to parallelize the computation in the light of the above considerations, it may become clear which choice to make.